# Elasticbeanstalk app Error 502 bad gateway but app is running

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs

I deployed an app using nodejs, nestjs and elasticbeanstalk. The app is running okey, actually if I access wiith the IP directly is working, but apparently something wrong is with nginx since when I access via de dns provided by elasticbeanstak it throws the 502 error bad gateway.
I changed the port to 8081 already. I don't come up with any idea I have no idea what can be happening. I also opened the ports 8081 and even I allowed access to everything to everyone, and still getting the error.
Anyone could help me? I have nothing to share because everything seems to be working fine.
The error in logs is:

> 2/08/01 09:40:17 [error] 29965#29965: *68 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 172.31.41.60, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host:
> "my-app.my-zone-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer:
> "http://my-app.my-zone.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
> 2022/08/01 09:40:20 [error] 29965#29965: *71 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 172.31.41.60, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.34.87" 2022/08/01 09:40:22
> [error] 29965#29965: *73 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
> while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.23.252, server: ,
> request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host:
> "172.31.34.87"

Comment: Did you look at the other logs for your application? I would look through each of those carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In my env variables I had the port under a different name than "PORT". For some reason EB waits for a "PORT" variable. So I modified and started working.
Also I changed the port from 8081 to 8080.